# Javascript remove duplicates from multidimentional array based on first element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get unique values from a multidimensional array.

The checking should be done based on the first element of each item.

```
let arr = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 1', 'item 5'],['item 3', 'item 4'], ['item 6', 'item 5']]
```

So here `item 1` is present multiple times so it should return

```
let arr = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 3', 'item 4'], ['item 6', 'item 5']]
```

Tried this snippet but its checking each and every value of element

```
 var uniques = [];
  var itemsFound = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
    if (itemsFound[stringified]) {
      continue;
    }
    uniques.push(arr[i]);
    itemsFound[stringified] = true;
  }
  return uniques;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the exact same result you shown (but oly works for two-dimensional arrays such as the example you gave):

```
const arr = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 1', 'item 5'],['item 3', 'item 4'], ['item 6', 'item 5']];
const arr2 = Array
    .from(
        new Map(
            arr.reverse()
        )
    )
    .reverse()
;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
// -> [["item 1","item 2"],["item 3","item 4"],["item 6","item 5"]]
```

Alternative implementation using `Object.fromEntries` if available could be:

```
const arr = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 1', 'item 5'],['item 3', 'item 4'], ['item 6', 'item 5']];
const arr2 = Object
    .entries(
        Object.fromEntries(
            arr.reverse()
        )
    )
    .reverse()
;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
// -> [["item 1","item 2"],["item 3","item 4"],["item 6","item 5"]]
```

...even this would be theoretically less performant than the former.

**BUT,** if I understood you well, you want to skip repeated values **at any position** in the inner array (not just first one).

In your input example also `'item 5'` is repeated, but its first occurrence comes together with `'item 1`' which makes this tuple to be ignored.

Let's add new element: `['item 7', 'item 6']`: In previous example this tuple would pass:

```
// ...
// -> [["item 1","item 2"],["item 3","item 4"],["item 6","item 5"],["item 7","item 6"]]
```

So, if your intention is to take in account all elements, there is no other option than scanning all subelements:

```
const arr = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 1', 'item 5'],['item 3', 'item 4'], ['item 6', 'item 5'], ['item 7','item 6']];
const seen = new Set();
const arr2 = arr
    .filter(function hasRepetition(items) {
        if ( // Repetition found
            1 + items.findIndex(itm=>seen.has(itm))
        ) return false;
        items.map(seen.add, seen);
        return true;
    })
;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
// -> [["item 1","item 2"],["item 3","item 4"],["item 6","item 5"]]
```

...This solution also works --with any dimensions--.

**Edit:**

This solution works **for any length of both (2) dimensions**, obviously not for any number of dimensions unless properly tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` to keep track of unique values and based on it you can create your array of unique items using `array#reduce`.

```js
const arr = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 1', 'item 5'],['item 3', 'item 4'], ['item 6', 'item 5']],
      set = new Set(),
      result = arr.reduce((r, a) => {
        if(!set.has(a[0])){
          set.add(a[0]);
          r.push(a);
        }
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to 'keep' every item that doesn't match your condition is like so

`arr.filter(item => item[0] !== arr[0][0])`

note that it will delete the 1st item aswell, you can save the 1st item beforehand in a few ways.